# Cakephp test via phpunit that uses both POST and GET data

Tags: php, unit-testing, cakephp, phpunit, cakephp-2.0

I am building a test suite in Cakephp using its built in test framework. I am running into the following issue. I have a controller method that when executed makes use of both `GET` and `POST` data. I know that to simulate `GET` data via a test you can easily include that as followed:

```
$result = $this->testAction('/api/checkuser/', array('data' => $data, 'method' => 'get');
```

The same thing can be done for `POST` as followed:

```
$result = $this->testAction('/api/currentuser/', array('data' => $data, 'method' => 'post');
```

But I'm not sure how I would use both together. Does anyone know how to send `POST` and `GET` data to a given test. Thanks to anyone that can help.

Comment: what about `$this->testAction('/api/checkuser/10', array('data' => $data, 'method' => 'post')` ?  So you are sending the user id through get and the rest with POST

Comment: @cornelb That sounds like what I'll have to do. Good idea.

Answer (score 1):

I have never had to send both GET and POST data and the same time, but if you can I imagine it would be something like.

$result = $this->testAction('/api/currentuser/', array('data' => $data, 'method' => array('post', 'get'));

Hope this helps.